# How to install PyGObject on windows in a anaconda virtual env

Tags: python-3.x, gtk, anaconda, gtk3, pygobject

I want to use Gtk with python under windows.  I already have Anaconda installed on windows.  In order not to mess up everything and to have some easiness uninstalling/reinstalling, I would like to have a virtual env created with `conda`, working with that Gtk installation.  But I don't seems to be able to make it work.

Here is my process.  I first create a raw Ananconda virtual env with

```
conda create -n gtk-exporter python
```

The virtual environment is located at `C:\Anaconda3\envs\gtk-exporter`.

I then download the latest windows installer for PyGObject at http://sourceforge.net/projects/pygobjectwin32/files/?source=navbar

I extract and execute the installer and tell it to use a portable python install at `C:\Anaconda3\envs\gtk-exporter`.  I only select Base, GTK and Glade for installation.  The installation finished in a second and says it's successful.

Then within windows' shell, I activate the new environment with `activate gtk-exporter`.  However when I try to import gtk, it fails, not finding `gi.repository`.

```
>>> from gi.repository import Gtk
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'gi'
```

What's wrong here ?  `C:\Anaconda3\envs\gtk-exporter\Lib\site-package` contains a folder `gnome` with a lot of stuff including `*.dll`s, `*.exe`'s and unix-looking folders like `etc`, `lib` or `share`, but I don't see a **init**.py or something pythonic.  Am I missing a step.

Thank you for your help !

Comment: Sorry but it doesn't work at all.  First I have no package manager under windows.  Also, I already copied the gtk files under folder site-packages, with the installer.  It put them under folder "site-packages/gnome".  Finally using symobolic links from site-packages/* to site-packages/gnome/* yield no more success

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I used python 3.5, whereas it is not supported.  The installer should not have allowed me to install with python 3.5. I filed a bug report to signal it.

I solved the problem by uninstalling python 3.5 and installing python 3.4.